# How can I import a Facebook Login Sample in Android Studio?

Tags: android, facebook-login

I am trying to integrate Facebook Login into my App and was going through the samples provided by Facebook on Github:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/LoginSample

Above is the Login Sample that I want to try out but seeing the project structure, I could only see `build.gradle` and not any other standard Android project files. I tried importing this sample as a project but ended up with a *incomplete* project which doesn't recognize any Android Module, nor there is any aapt compiler configured. It also complains about the `AndroidManifest.xml`, assets folder, etc.

I tried, creating an Android facet through **Project Structure** settings, but still the project doesn't get recognized as a full fledged Android project.

Is there any way, I can have it as an Android project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to clone or download the [facebook-android-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) repository. Once you download it just try to open it in Android Studio, you will be able to access LoginSample or other modules as an Android Project.